# Issue loading and accessing 2D array

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays

In jquery/javascript the array has following structure. And I am able to fetch the data using, data[cartIndex].rows[i].

```
//cartIndex is anything from 0 to 10;
//row is like [name, quantity, balance, remarks]

for (var i=0; i < data[cartIndex].length; i++) {
            var row = data[cartIndex].rows[i];
            alert(row.name, row.quantity, row.balance);
}
```

I used both a list and an array to populate data in C# and serialized it.

---

UPDATED CODE:

```
        var arrList = new List<object>();

        string x = string.Empty;
        int i = table.Rows.Count;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string name = row[0].ToString();
            string quantity = row[1].ToString();
            string balance = row[2].ToString();
            string remove = "X";

            arrList.Add(new Wrapper { rows = new [] { name, quantity, balance, remove }});
        }

        var maList = new List<object>();
        maList.Add(arrList);            
        return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(maList);
```

But somehow it's not in the correct column row format in javascript.

```
data = [
         [[name, quantity, balance, remarks], 
            [name, quantity, balance, remarks], 
            [name, quantity, balance, remarks]
         ],
         [[name, quantity, balance, remarks], 
            [name, quantity, balance, remarks], 
            [name, quantity, balance, remarks]
         ]         
       ]
```

With this, I am not able to access the array rows like this:

```
var row = data[cartIndex].rows[i];
//row.name gives name, row.quantity gives quantity and so on
```

This structure should also allow to push a row into the array.

```
data[cartIndex].length++;
data[cartIndex].rows.push({name: name, 
quantity: quantity, balance: blance});
```

How can I structure the c# array to be accessed via row indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data in the second dimension like this:

```
var name= data[cartIndex][0];
var quantiry = data[cartIndex][1];
// And so on...
```

The property `data[cartIndex].rows` will not work because the object you are adding to the list from the server side does not have a property `rows`

Alternatively, you can change your server code as follows:

```
// Add a new wrapper class
public class Wrapper{
    public string[] rows{ get;set;}
}
```

And change the line where you add the rows to the list as follows:

```
alist.Add(new Wrapper { rows = new [] {name, quantity, balance, remove}});
```

Comment: Because of this `alist.Add(new [] {name, quantity, balance, remove});`

Comment: To get the rows property working, it should be something like `alist.Add(new SomeWrapperClass { rows = new [] {name, quantity, balance, remove}});`

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the c# code? Is it a must to use a Wrapper class, isn't there a native way to formulate an array like this with rows in C#? Because there are functions which uses rows property alot in the js file `data[cartIndex].rows.push(`

Comment: Answer updated, Yes, you can do this in a one line code using `Linq` and `Anonymous Types` instead of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I tried your code, but the array looks like this now: `var data = [[{"rows":["Jorge","25","20","X"]},{"rows":["Jacques","50","10","X"]},{"rows":["Bell","10","10","X"]}]];` it doesn't seem to have a row index. I prefer not to use linq at this point, until this thing gets solved with the forloop.

Comment: Are you adding `alist` to another list before sending to the client?

Comment: That extra list `maList` is creating a useless extra array with only one element in the js side. Please remove that and send the `arrList` instead like this `return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(arrList);` and you are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78978/discussion-between-aspiring-and-xmindz).